# Close CSS dropdown menu on click elsewhere on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, touch

Although this question has been asked before, I haven't been able to find a working solution anywhere yet, so here goes...

I have a normal pure CSS nav menu with submenus (using :hover) on a responsive site. Everything works fine except that on touch devices if you open a submenu and decide not to click on a link, it doesn't close even if you touch elsewhere else on the page.

Is there any way to have the submenu close on click elsewhere for touch devices but keep the :hover functionality for desktop users?

Thanks!

PS. I'm very new to JS and jQuery, so answers with examples would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not use onclick method?

Comment: How would I do that for just touch devices whilst leaving hover for desktop?

Comment: You can do that via specifying the screen size with JQuery. For example, if you want tablet only you can do `if ( $(window).width() < 739) {     
  //Add your javascript for large screens here
}`

Comment: Touch devices do not have ":hover" mode. Therefore you use something else to "activate" your "CSS dropdown menu". True?

Comment: @Yevgeniy Afanasyev - Thanks for the answer and comment, however it does activate (technically) 'on hover' even on touch devices due to touch events which simulate hover. So opening the dropdown isn't an issue, but closing on touch is. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: @Blkc - That sounds like it should work, but preferably the other way around (ie. setting the js for smaller rather than larger screens). What would be some example code to make it open/close on click for the smaller screens? Sorry, as above I'm very new to js!

Comment: some touch-screen devices trigger the :hover event before the click event so you will have such response for a brief moment before the click would be done, but eventually it would be click. You may NOT have hover without click on touch-screen devices.

Comment: @Biks - I have full size computers ALL-IN-ONE with 23" touch-screens. You cannot judge if it is touch-screen or not based on the  screen width. Here is the example http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-2350-aio/pd

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev - I see. I didn't consider those computers. I think the best way to approach this problem would be to not use :hover because personally I just hate hover on slow computers in general. If you want the site to work well on any computers, stick with clicks

Comment: @annie123 can you, please, make a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see what exactly you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use "click anywhere else" to close your menu, it will not affect "hover" functionality, but these two ways of hiding menu will compete. It mean that you have one extra limitation - "make sure it is visible when handling click". Use this:

```
if($('#hover_settings').is(":visible")){
                //do something
}
```

Lets's say, you have "#button_settings" on the main form and '#hover_settings' menu that become visible or hidden. You click "#button_settings" to hide and to show '#hover_settings' and it works perfectly unless you decide to have same effect to hide '#hover_settings' from clicking anywhere else, but within '#hover_settings'.

First - how to hide '#hover_settings'?

```
        $(document).click(function() {
            if($('#hover_settings').is(":visible")){
                $('#button_settings').click();
            }
        });
```

Second - #button_settings - how it should work?

```
        $('#button_settings').click(function(){
            var $hs = $('#hover_settings');
            if($hs.is(":visible")){                 
                $hs.hide({effect: "slide", direction : 'up'}, 500);
            }else{
                $hs.show({effect: "slide", direction : 'up'}, 500);                 
            };
            return false;
        });
```

Third - limitation - as you have a menu and you may expect two variants of behaviour after click on each element

a) perform action and close menu - you don't need to do anything.

b) perform action and leave menu open - you need to finish this on-click function without Propagation, to do so try:

```
return false;
```

or

```
e.stopPropagation();
```